# Rss Feed Parse in ruby Using Nokogiri when feed have `CDATA` `tag`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [trying to get content inside cdata tags in xml file using nokogiri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476783/trying-to-get-content-inside-cdata-tags-in-xml-file-using-nokogiri)

My code is this

```
 doc= Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.seattlepi.com/local/feed/seattlepi-com-Local-News-218.php", 'User-Agent' => 'ruby'))

title=data.css("title").text
description=data.css("description").text
link = data.at("link").next_sibling.text
```

and i get description,title and link all blank because feed present `CDATA` `tag`
So please tell me how can i parse it
Thanks

Comment: Besides the answer at the Duplicate, you are passing a File, not a String. Try making a string from the XML first, e.g. with `open().read`

Comment: Nokogiri will `read` from an open file handle so it's not necessary to do it explicitly first. It's the same behavior that allows us to pass an `open` after requiring OpenURI.